# How can I do a kind of distinct using Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this array which contains some dictionaries :

```
a = [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]
```

But I tried to do this : `list(set(a))` and it does not work unfortunately  I get this :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Do you know how can I solve this I mean I would like to have :

```
a = [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]
```

Thank you !

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Your post and especially the question are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
[dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in a}]
```

This will convert the list of dictionaries to a list of tuples, each tuple contains the items of the dictionary. Now, tuples can be hashed, different from dictionaries. We remove using a set comprehension.

Another alternative would be:

```
set(tuple(d.items()) for d in a)
```

Which returns `{(('name', 'Peter'), ('email', ''), ('color', 'red'))}`, now you would need to reconstruct the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Django question, but a general Python question.

You cannot use a `set` to get unique members of any iterable if those members are not hashable.

One simple way is to use `itertools.groupby` in conjunction with sorting the outer `list` by each `dict`'s values:

```
a = [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
 {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]

from itertools import groupby

uniques = [key for key, _ in groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda d: tuple(d.values())))]

print(uniques)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also exploit the fact that a dictionary cannot have repeating same keys. Specifically, you can use `update`

```
arr = [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
       {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'},
       {'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]

arr1 = {}
for d in arr:
    for k, v in d.items():
        arr1.update({k: v})
print ([arr1])        
# [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': '', 'color': 'red'}]
```